# JavaScript - CSS Generator

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: у нас есть инпуты *height, width, left, right*. Для изменения значений через ползунок мы создаем функцию, достаем значение, а дальше что? Гляньте код, как делать? Пожалуйста, объясните понять не могу.

```js
function sizeHeight() {
    height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
body{
  background: #1d1d1d;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block{
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.button{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
input{
  display: block;
}
p{
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<hr/>
<div class="button">
  <p>Height</p><input id="heigh" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" oninput="sizeHeight()">
  <p>Width</p><input id="width" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <p>Left</p><input id="left" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <p>Right</p><input id="right" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```js
function sizeHeight(hVal) {
    block = document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0];
    block.style.height = hVal + "px";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
body{
  background: #1d1d1d;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block{
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.button{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
input{
  display: block;
}
p{
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<hr/>
<div class="button">
  <p>Height</p><input id="height" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" onchange="sizeHeight(this.value)">
  <p>Width</p><input id="width" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <p>Left</p><input id="left" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <p>Right</p><input id="right" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Я изменил и в JS написал
function sizeHeight() {
    height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    height.style.height = this.value + 'px';
}
все равно не работает

Comment: @AleksandrYakovlev да у вас нет элемента с ID `height` в вашей HTML разметке

Comment: Я изменил в разметке на height

Comment: @AleksandrYakovlev обновил ответ

Comment: http://codepen.io/Vaynshtein/pen/yMvePw не работает.

Answer (score 0):

1. Делегировать событие `input` от блока `.button` к инпутам, ловить всплывающее событие при помощи `e.target`.
2. Проверять айди инпута и менять соответствующие свойства.
3. Использовать вместо `left/right` `transform: translateX(Xpx)`.

```js
var block = document.querySelector('.block'),
    btn = document.querySelector('.button');

btn.addEventListener('input', setProperties);

function setProperties(e) {
  var prop, val;
  
  if( e.target.matches('input[type=range]') ) {
    prop = e.target.id,
    val = e.target.value + 'px';
    
    if (prop === 'left') block.style.transform = 'translateX(' + val + ')'
    else if (prop === 'right') block.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + val + ')'
    else block.style[prop] = val
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
body{
  background: #1d1d1d;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block{
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.button{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
input{
  display: block;
}
p{
  color: white;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<hr/>
<div class="button">
  <p>Height</p><input id="height" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <p>Width</p><input id="width" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <p>Left</p><input id="left" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
  <p>Right</p><input id="right" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0">
</div>
```